# symfony form type translation_domain not working?

Tags: forms, symfony, dns, translation

i have form type like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', null, [
            'translation_domain' => 'Admin.Global',
        ])
        ->add('isoCode', null, [
            'translation_domain' => 'Admin.Global',
        ])
        ->add('languageCode')
        ->add('flag_image', FileType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => 'flag',
            'constraints' => [
                new Image([
                    'maxSize' => '1024K'
                ])
            ],
            'required' => false,
            'translation_domain' => 'Admin.Global',
        ])
        ->add('active', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => 'switch-custom'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('isDefault', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => 'switch-custom'
            ]
        ]);
}
```

after i run command:

```
php bin/console translation:update --force en(or zh_CN)
```

only 'name' label in Admin.Global+intl-icu.en(or zh_CN).xlf file

why the isocode and flag not on xlf file?
and do i add 'translation_domain' => 'Admin.Global', to each formtype?

Comment: Try changing the `name` field in this form into a key that is not found anywhere else in your project. For example, use `name123` instead of `name`. Run the command again and see if the `name123` key gets into the xlf file. I'm pretty sure, it won't get there.

Comment: @xtx i change it to name123 or i add 'label'=>'name1234', not work too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `translation:update` command, according to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#extracting-translation-contents-and-updating-catalogs-automatically),
extracts strings to translate from 2 locations only:

- templates
- any PHP file/class that injects or autowires the translator service and makes calls to the trans() method.

Your form type class is neither of these two, so it is not processed.

You mentioned that the name label gets into xlf file, while other labels do not. Obviously, name got there from some other place (from a template, for example), not from the form class.

To process form type classes you can install [JMSTranslationBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle).
It provides a different command, `translation:extract`, which among other things supports extracting messages from (a quote from [docs](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle/master/usage#extracting-translation-messages)):

> all form labels that are defined as options to the ->add() method of
> the FormBuilder